# Inserting values from an array of objects into a set of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, key-value

I have an array of objects and would like to insert their values into a set of inputs. I thought that using jQuery's `val()` to mass assign these values within a few for-loops but it only returns the very last value of the two objects. What am I doing wrong? Better yet, **is there a better way to do this without having to loop 3 times**?

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = [{v1: 1, v2: 2, v3: 3, v4: 4}, {v1: 5, v2: 6, v3: 7, v4: 8}];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (key in arr[i]) {
      $('input').val(function(index) {
        return arr[i][key]
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Is it correct to assume that the structure of `arr` cannot be changed?

Comment: Correct. I'm retrieving these objects from an API but hardcoded an small array here for demonstration's sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('input')` will retrieve all 8 inputs on the page. So when you call `$('input').val(newVal)` you're setting the value of *all 8 inputs*. That's why all of the inputs have the last value after your code runs.

One solution is to retrieve all inputs at first and iterate through the inputs:

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = [{v1: 1, v2: 2, v3: 3, v4: 4}, {v1: 5, v2: 6, v3: 7, v4: 8}];
  var $inputs = $("input");
  var currentIndex = 0;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (key in arr[i]) {
      $inputs.eq(currentIndex++).val(arr[i][key]);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

And no, I cannot think of a way to accomplish this task without at least 2 loops. There are items in the array to iterate over, and items within the objects in the array to iterate over.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation. One question though. How does `currentIndex++` iterate itself being that it originally starts at 0? Wouldn't it keep returning 0?

Comment: @CarlEdwards The `++` is the [Post Increment Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_%28%29). `currentIndex` will return its value, then be incremented by 1. This is the same operator as the `i++` in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you put all the `<input>` in a single `<div>` you can use this way

```
var arr = [{v1: 1, v2: 2, v3: 3, v4: 4}, {v1: 5, v2: 6, v3: 7, v4: 8}];
var c = 1;
$inputs = $('input');
$.each(arr, function(i){
   $.each(arr[i], function(j){
     $('input:nth-child('+[c]+')').val(arr[i][j]);
     c++;
   })
});
```

You can see it at work in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreIDK/k48v8y0m/)